# Go + Azure: Calling a method return undefined

Tags: azure, go

Am trying to use Go Azure SDK to call the notification hub api

I have installed the SDK and imported to the GO file :

```
package hub

import (

    "fmt"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/notificationhubs"
)

func GetHub() {
    if resourceType, err := notificationhubs.Get("sourceGroupName", "NameSpaceValue", "NameOfTheHub"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error occured")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Success")

}
```

However when am trying to runt he code i got this error

```
undefined: notificationhubs.Get
```

And am not sure what it means since my IDE don't complain about importing the Azure SDK so am assuming the SDK is imported correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're trying to use doesn't exist (https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/notificationhubs).

You're probably trying to use the function [`GroupClient.Get`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/notificationhubs#GroupClient.Get); if that's the case, you need to get an object of type `GroupClient` and then call the function `Get` on it.

Answer (score 0):

@cd1 is correct! The Get method doesn't belong directly to namespace that you've imported, but rather a client that exists in that namespace. In order to interact with NotificationsHub in this manner, instantiate a `GroupClient` then run a `Get` command.

```
import (
    hubs "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/notificationshub"
)

func main() {
    // Implementation details of your program ...
    client := hubs.NewGroupClient("<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>")
    client.Authorizer = // Your initialized Service Principal Token

    results, err := client.Get("<RESOURCE GROUP NAME>", "<NAMESPACE NAME>", "<NOTIFICATION HUB NAME>")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```